# How can I make a python application always appear on the active desktop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

How can I make a python3 application for linux always appear on the active desktop? I want this application to not only appear on whatever desktop/workspace that is being used...I also want it to be treated as part of the background in the way that conky or a desktop widget would be, meaning desktop/window manager decorations would not be applied...as if it were a root window.

I am stuck for an idea. I have searched for libraries that might help with this but have found nothing that seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout  this library  to see if its helpful to make To make a Python3 application for Linux always appear on the active desktop and be treated as part of the background, `python-xlib` along with the `wmctrl` command-line tool. here is github [repo](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib) of library.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion  led me to what I was looking for...I added these to my main window class   :                      self.setWindowFlag(Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint)
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

Comment: nice to hear, upvote it  is helpful for, finding your solution